# How to use posts as tabs in a custom page?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, theme-development, pages, javascript

everyone. I'm a beginner at coding/Wordpress and need some help with a custom page I'm developing right now. The idea is simple:

- A list of items on the left
- An image with a description below on the right

Each item on the list, when clicked, would change the image and description displayed on the right, sort of how tabs work. It should be possible to delete and add items from the dashboard, so I thought of using a custom post type. Each new post would be added to the list and its content would be available when the user clicks on it.

The problem is, I have no idea of how to make this work with Wordpress. I know tabs work, but I'm struggling with how to get all the post info, how to display the right one when the title is clicked, how to make the "tabs" work with new posts being added or deleted, etc. Any tips on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I offer you a solution composed of three parts:

1 - Create a CTP.

2 - Create the necessary javascript and css scripts.

3 - Create a dedicated template in the root of your theme `archive-$posttype.php`, in our example will be `archive-product.php`

I created a repo in my git where you can download the Plugin here is the link: [Custom CPT](https://github.com/younes-dro/dro-cpt)

The source code for the `archive-product.php` page is here: [archive-product](https://gist.github.com/younes-dro/5243eae124a35b7365c161965e8d7e87)

So you can download them directly to test and adapt them to your needs.
I used the `twentynineeen` theme, you have to create a physical page named: `archive-product.php` and its code is indicated above in the gist.
The JS and CSS code is quite basic, so improve it for your needs.

The main file  :

```
/**
* Plugin Name:     Dro Cpt
* Plugin URI:      PLUGIN SITE HERE
* Description:     PLUGIN DESCRIPTION HERE
* Author:          YOUR NAME HERE
* Author URI:      YOUR SITE HERE
* Text Domain:     dro-cpt
* Domain Path:     /languages
* Version:         0.1.0
*
* @package         Dro_Cpt
*/ 
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
// Hook our Plugin 
  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'dro_cpt' );

  function dro_cpt() {

/**
 * Create our CPT
*/
   add_action( 'init', function() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Products', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Product'),
        'new_item' => __('New Product'),
        'all_items' => __('All Products'),
        'view_item' => __('View Product'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Products'),
        'not_found' => __('No products found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in the Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Products'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'has_archive' => true, // Enabling a post type archive at http://yoursite.com/product
    );
    register_post_type( 'product', $args ); // thanks  Daniel Pataki
} );
}

/**
* Enqueue the js and css juste for our CPT .
*/
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
global $wp_query;
// Load the assets juste for our CPT archive page.
if ( $wp_query->is_post_type_archive('product') ) {

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dro_cpt_scripts' );

    function dro_cpt_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'dro-cpt-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/dro-cpt.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', TRUE );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'dro-cpt-css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/css/dro-cpt.css' );
    }

}
});
```

The `archive-product.php` (`twentynineteen/archive-product.php`) :

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive pages
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Nineteen
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

get_header();
?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
                    <div class="dro-cpt">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                                the_title('<a class="dro-cpt-tab" href="#" data-id="'.get_the_ID().'">','</a>',TRUE);
                                echo '<div class="dro-cpt-description" id= "description-'.get_the_ID().'">';
                                the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
                                echo '<div class=" single-description " >'.the_content().'</div>';
                                echo "</div>";
                // End the loop.
            endwhile;

            // Previous/next page navigation.
            twentynineteen_the_posts_navigation();

            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
                        <div class="dro-cpt-display"></div>
                    </div><!-- .dro-cpt -->
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

The js ( `plugins/dro-cpt/assets/dro-cpt.js`) :

```
(function($){

    // show the first element
    var firstDescr =  $('div.dro-cpt-description').first().html();
    $('div.dro-cpt-display').html(firstDescr);

    $('a.dro-cpt-tab').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var desc = $('#description-'+id).html();
        console.log(desc);
        $('div.dro-cpt-display').html(desc);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The CSS  (`plugins/dro-cpt/assets/dro-cpt.css`):

```
div.dro-cpt{

    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.dro-cpt a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
div.dro-cpt a:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dro-cpt-description{
    display: none;
}
div.dro-cpt-display{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```